# I'm not able to load my HTML page using ngroute module from angularjs. My code looks fine to me. What mistake am I making?Please review the code

Tags: html, angularjs

Below is index.html.I'm trying load home.html on the home page.

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html ng-app="instagram">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compitable" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Instagram</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.0/paper/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/1.5.2/css/ionicons.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><i class="ion-images"></i> instagram</a>
          <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#/login">Log in</a></li>
          <li><a href="#/signup">Sign up</a></li>
          <li><a ng-click="logout()" href="">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ngview></div>
    <script src="Vendor/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Vendor/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="Vendor/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/home.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/login.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/signup.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/detail.js"></script>
    <script src="Controllers/navbar.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

below is my app.js. It does not redirect to home.html.

```
    angular.module('instagram', ['ngRoute', 'ngMessages']).
      config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
          .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'Views/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
          })
          .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'Views/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
          })
          .when('/signup', {
            templateUrl: 'Views/signup.html',
            controller: 'SignupCtrl'
          })
          .when('/photo/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'Views/detail.html',
            controller: 'DetailCtrl'
          })
          .otherwise('/');

      });
```

I tried all the solutions which are available on stackoverflow. But I'm not able to resolve my error. It's also not throwing any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ng-view,

```
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="nav">
            <a href="#login" class="button">Login</a></a>
            <a href="#signup" class="button">Signup</a>
            <a href="#detail" class="button">Detail</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div ng-view=""></div>
    </div>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/1dKBW2ooc5pwjoeWbH6F?p=preview)**

Comment: Hey Thank you so much. It worked. Have a great day.!!

Answer (score 1):

**please replace your ng-view Directive**

`<div ngview> </div>`

**with**

```
`<div ng-view> </div>`
```